# Cannot access variable declared outside of Switch Statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, scope, switch-statement

I am declaring a variable `contactNumber` outside of a switch statement and then trying to assign it inside the switch statement. However, when it reaches the assignment, I get an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`  on the assignment line executed inside the switch statement

```
function helplineContactMessageForCountryCode(countryCode) {

    var contactNumber = ''
    switch (countryCode) {
        case 'NG':
        contactNumber = '234-01-772-2200'
        break

        case 'UG':
        contactNumber = '0800-100-330'
        break

        case 'US'
        contactNumber = '1-800-232-4636'
        break

        case 'ZA':
        contactNumber = '0800-012-322'
        break

        default:
        //Return empty string if no country code is found
        return ''
    }
    return 'You can try calling the Toll-Free HIV and AIDS Helpline and speak to a human - ' + contactNumber
}
```

Comment: Take that `return` out of the switch and replace it with `contactNumber = ''; break;` Or you can take the `default` right out of the switch. And there is a missing `:` after 'US'

Comment: Typo? Missing `:` after `case 'US'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `:` after the "US" `case`.

```js
function helplineContactMessageForCountryCode(countryCode) {

  var contactNumber = ''
  switch (countryCode) {
    case 'NG':
      contactNumber = '234-01-772-2200';
      break;
    case 'UG':
      contactNumber = '0800-100-330';
      break;
    case 'US':
      contactNumber = '1-800-232-4636';
      break;
    case 'ZA':
      contactNumber = '0800-012-322';
      break;
    default:
      contactNumber = contactNumber;
      break;
  }
  return 'You can try calling the Toll-Free HIV and AIDS Helpline and speak to a human - ' + contactNumber
}
```

Comment: Please just flag/vote to close as a typo, instead of answering.

Comment: Omg lol I must have lost about an hour to this. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **:** in  case 'US'. After you add it it should work as attended.

I would also suggest using object map instead of switch statement for you precise use case to make code shorten and nicer

```
function helplineContactMessageForCountryCode(countryCode) {
  const codeMap = {
    NG: '234-01-772-2200',
    UG: '0800-100-330',
    US: '1-800-232-4636',
    ZA: '1-800-232-4636'
  };

  var number = codeMap[countryCode];
  if (number) {
    return 'You can try calling the Toll-Free HIV and AIDS Helpline and speak to a human - ' + number;
  }
  return '';
}
```

in example codeMap is set inside helplineContactMessageForCountryCode but ideally it should be declared somewhere else.

Comment: Please just flag as a typo, instead of answering.